# Jinja2 {% include file %} outside of search path doesn't work

Tags: python, jinja2

This is an elementary issue which is probably related to Jinja2 PrefixLoader or ChoiceLoader.

On Python 3.6 we load with this command

```
jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath= "\\template_folder\\")
```

On Windows 7, our file structure is as follows.

```
- folder_bbb
    * subfile.txt
- template_folder
     * template_file
     - folder_aaa
         * subfile.txt
```

From the template_file we are successful with this command

```
{% include "folder_aaa/subfile.txt" %}
```

Now we wish to move the file one level up, and write

```
{% include "../folder_bbb/subfile.txt" %}
```

but that doesn't work, complaining file not found.

What is the correct way to write? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may specify all paths in the the loader

```
jinja2.FileSystemLoader(["c:\\template_folder\\", "c:\\folder_bbb\\"])
```

and refer the including block without a specific path

```
{% include "subfile.txt" %}
```

The path will be searched in order so that as you say, moving the file one level up, the file will be found. (You need the template_folder path for the template itself.)