# Include Html file inside the html file which is present in static folder using jinja in python flask

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I want to Include Html file inside the Html file Using jinja 
Here Is My Python Code:

```
@app.route('/sample')
def sample():
    return render_template('sample1.html')
```

And Here is My sample1.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>KrisHnA Creations</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
      {% include '/static/myfile.html'   %}
```

But I got an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /static/myfile.html
```

Any One Know Solution For This ??

Pls answer me

Comment: you can read `myfile.html` in `sample()` and send HTML as argument `render_template('sample1.html', data=html_from_file)` And then in template you have to use `{{ data | safe }}`

Comment: [Jinja2 {% include file %} outside of search path doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058873/jinja2-include-file-outside-of-search-path-doesnt-work/50064948)

Comment: good solution. What if there should be multiple insertions?